# template based Sin() implementation based on taylor series produces incorrect results C++

Tags: c++, templates, taylor-series

```
template<unsigned I>
struct factorial{
    enum{

    value = I * factorial<I -1>::value
    };

};
template<>
struct factorial<0>
{
    enum{ value = 1};
};

template<unsigned pow>
inline double power(double const& value){
    return value * power<pow-1>(value);
}
template<>
inline double power<1>(double const& value){
    return value;
}
template<>
inline double power<0>(double const& value){
    return 1;
}

template<unsigned term>
inline double taylor_polynomial(double const& x){
    return power<term>(x) / factorial<term>::value;
}

template <unsigned term>
inline double taylor_sine_term(double const& x) {
    return (power<term>(-1) / factorial<(2*term)+1>::value) * power<(2*term)+1>(x);
}

template<unsigned terms>
inline double taylor_sine(double const& x){
    return taylor_sine_term<terms-1>(x) + taylor_sine_term<terms>(x);
}
template <>
inline double taylor_sine<0>(double const& x) {
    return taylor_sine_term<0>(x);
}
```

Using the following code I have attempted to implement the `sin()` function based on an N term taylor series, but when i compare the results of the function the results are incorrect and I'm not sure why. Running the following code:

```
std::cout<<sin(2 * M_PI * 0.5)<<"   "<<taylor_sine<13>(2 * M_PI * 0.5);
```

Results in `1.22465e-16   -16546.9`

To the best of my knowledge i am calculating the series correctly so i'm not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: That's a Maclaurin series. It's centred at zero, not π.

Comment: Did you first try a non-metaprogram version of your implementation to verify it gives the correct results?

Comment: @chris so that would mean an input range of `-pi to pi`? rather than `0 - 2pi`?

Comment: @AlexZywicki, In this case, the radius of convergence is ∞, so the Maclaurin series will converge at x=π (and any other x), but that isn't true for every power series.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the wrong function to recurse:

```
template<unsigned terms>
inline double taylor_sine(double const& x){
    return taylor_sine_term<terms-1>(x) + taylor_sine_term<terms>(x);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

You're adding term `n` and term `n-1` instead of adding term `n` and the taylor series of `n-1` terms.

Comment: `template<unsigned terms>
inline double taylor_sine(double const& x){
    return taylor_sine_term<terms>(x) + taylor_sine<terms-1>(x);
}` Like this?